# Using a select case statement to compare field values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using a select case statement to compare two columns. One value is returned from a table valued function and the other is a database column. If the first value of Preferred First Name is null then I need to show the value of FirstName from a view as a aliased column.
I dont know if my syntax is right. Can someone tell me if this is right and or a better way to do it?

```
(SELECT 
     CASE WHEN (
        Select ASSTRING
        FROM dbo.GetCustomFieldValue('Preferred First Name', view_Attendance_Employees.FileKey)
     ) = NULL 
 THEN view_Attendance_Employees.FirstName
    ELSE (
        Select ASSTRING
       FROM dbo.GetCustomFieldValue('Preferred First Name', view_Attendance_Employees.FileKey))
   END) as FirstName,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [isnull](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function here:

```
select isnull(.. Massive subquery here..., FirstName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL` when comparing with `NULL`.

But in your case you should use `ISNULL` like so:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(
        SELECT ASSTRING
        FROM dbo.GetCustomFieldValue('Preferred First Name', view_Attendance_Employees.FileKey),
        view_Attendance_Employees.FirstName
    ) AS FirstName,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your code correctly, this may be a bit cleaner way of doing it.

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT 
        FirstName
    ,   AsString = ( Select ASSTRING FROM dbo.GetCustomFieldValue('Preferred First Name', X.FileKey) )
    FROM view_Attendance_Employees X
)

SELECT FirstName = ISNULL(AsString,FirstName)
FROM CTE
```

Comment: That is clean. I like.